# Select aggregate with respect to each different column separately

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I wanted to select each unique title, along with the related link. I want to choose the sum(price) with respect to title and sum(price) with respect to link in each record. This is my table structure:

| title | link | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 5 |
| a | 1 | 10 |
| b | 2 | 15 |
| c | 2 | 20 |

Expected output:

| link | title | title_price | link_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 15 | 15 |
| 2 | b | 15 | 35 |
| 2 | c | 20 | 35 |

Here's my attempt:

```
"SELECT link as link, title, sum(price) FROM `test` group by link,title"
```

This was tried in order to select the sum with respect to title but I also wanted to select sum with respect to link too in each row. So I use following query but it gives error:

```
SELECT t1.link as link, title, sum(price) as title_price,
(select link_price from(
(select link, sum(price) as link_price from `test` group by link where link=t1.link)
))
as price
FROM `test` as t1 group by link,title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use sum aggregate function to find the sum for each title, link group, then use sum window function to find the sum for each link group.

```
SELECT link, title, sum_per_link_title AS title_price,
  SUM(sum_per_link_title) OVER (PARTITION BY link) AS link_price
FROM
(
  SELECT title, link, SUM(price) AS sum_per_link_title
  FROM test
  GROUP BY title, link
) T
ORDER BY link, title
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qkvg8ErX).